# What data is stored in DHCID RR by rfc 4701 (in lay terms)?

Tags: dhcp, isc-dhcp

To understand what is going on my dhcp server I need to understand what is stored in this record that idenities my dhcp clients.

I have long read this standart. But cannot understand.

In lay terms I want to know what data relate to client is stored in this RR.

Comment: Maybe you should ask a question about the problem you have with your DHCP server instead?

Comment: Thanks. But I want to manually investigate a problem with a good background of what is going on )